# SQL Developer DB2->Oracle Migration Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate a DB2 on cloud database to oracle. I have downloaded SQL developer, added the correct JARs for the DB2 drivers and can run the migration successfully on the database.

The only part of the migration I'm struggling with is the conversion of the stored procedures which are not outputted in the ddl. This seems to be an issue with the language of the procedures; the migration log is showing the below:

```
<record>
  <date>2018-09-24T16:25:39</date>
  <logger>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>oracle.dbtools.migration.generate.GenerateWorker</class>
  <message>Stored Procedure '*****' has language id of 'DB2LANG' so will not output for generation</message>
  <key>Generate.PROCNOTCONVERTED</key>
  <catalog>oracle.dbtools.migration.workbench.core.MigrationLogResourceBundle</catalog>
  <param>*****</param>
  <param>DB2LANG</param>
  <param>*****, MD_STORED_PROGRAMS, 1864951Generate</param>

</record>
```

Has anyone got any experience in migrating DB2 stored procs, or knows if there is a way to avoid having to re-write all the stored procedures?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom,
DB2 stored procedures are not supported for translation.
B

Comment: there are some 3rd party (non-Oracle) solutions that offer to do this for a price

Comment: Thanks for the help guys; that's the conclusion I came to. Might be one to call out in the documentation as there was no mention of that limitation anywhere obvious. Cheers